# How to remove unwanted file from git

Tags: git, gitlab

I have pushed a branch without noticing the changes made under the branch. There is  a file named `\` in my remote branch. I have used `git rm \ .`. But no luck.Please help me to remove the file.

Thanks

Comment: You can delete the file in your branch and commit the deletion.

Comment: What exactly is "no luck"? What happens when you do that?

Comment: try using  quotes , it should work. git rm "\" or git rm '\'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash is very likely to be used as an escape character by your shell. To pass an actual backslash to the command line of a program, most shells allow you to escape it itself or use quotes to tell the shell not to interpret it specially.

`git rm \\`

`git rm '\'`

Answer (score 0):

To remove a file from Git, you have to remove it from your tracked files (more
accurately, remove it from your staging area) and then commit. The git rm
command does that, and also removes the file from your working directory so
you don’t see it as an untracked file the next time around.
If you simply remove the file from your working directory, it shows up under
the “Changed but not updated” (that is, unstaged) area of your git status
output:

```
$ rm PROJECTS.md
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
 (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
 (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
 deleted: PROJECTS.md
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Then, if you run git rm, it stages the file’s removal:

```
$ git rm PROJECTS.md
rm 'PROJECTS.md'
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
 (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
CHAPTER 2: Git Basics
56
 deleted: PROJECTS.md
```

The next time you commit, the file will be gone and no longer tracked. If you
modified the file and added it to the index already, you must force the removal
with the -f option. This is a safety feature to prevent accidental removal of data
that hasn’t yet been recorded in a snapshot and that can’t be recovered from
Git.
Another useful thing you may want to do is to keep the file in your working
tree but remove it from your staging area. In other words, you may want to
keep the file on your hard drive but not have Git track it anymore. This is particularly
useful if you forgot to add something to your .gitignore file and accidentally
staged it, like a large log file or a bunch of .a compiled files. To do this,
use the --cached option:

`$ git rm --cached README`

You can pass files, directories, and file-glob patterns to the git rm command.
That means you can do things such as:

`$ git rm log/\*.log`

Note the backslash () in front of the *. This is necessary because Git does its
own filename expansion in addition to your shell’s filename expansion. This
command removes all files that have the .log extension in the log/ directory.
Or, you can do something like this:

`$ git rm \*~`

This command removes all files that end with ~.